# Rolling file not generated using logback in tomcat log directory

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

I am first time using the logback logger, 
I have written the configuration file for generating rolling file in tomcat logs,
It generates log file named processlog.log but it did not generate the rolling file
like processlog.2014-05-29.log

Can anyone figure out,Whats wrong in configuration file ?

Here is my configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t] %c{1} - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ROLLING_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${catalina.home}/logs/processlog.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>processlog.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t] %c{1} - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <append>true</append>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.myproject" level="DEBUG"/>
    <root>
        <priority value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ROLLING_FILE"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<FileNamePattern>processlog.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
```

should be

```
<FileNamePattern>${catalina.home}/logs/processlog.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
```